# Is it possible to change content of rows during a dump?

Tags: mysql, row, updates

I would like to change the content of some rows during the dumb process for anonymization matters. (ex : name/address/etc.)

Is it even possible, and if so does anybody have an idea on how to do that ?

A simplified version of the database I want to dump :

```
|ID|NAME      |ADDRESS   |JOB            |
|0 |Elizabeth |address 1 |Dentist        |
|1 |Lionel    |address 2 |Baker          |
```

And i would like to have something randomize like this :

```
|ID|NAME      |ADDRESS           |JOB            |
|0 |Charles   |another address 1 |Dentist        |
|1 |Peter     |another address 2 |Baker          |
```

So, basically, I would like to "randomize" some columns and keep others as they are originally.

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Does it actually look like that? `mysqldump` usually outputs in a format that can be re-imported as-is. Has the table creation code, INSERT statements and everything all in SQL.

Comment: I mean, there is more columns, but the goal is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finaly solved it by coding a bash script whose goal is to create a temporary database, use the dump file on it so its possible to edit the datas directly with some basics SQL requests.

After this step done, the script will dump this new database before droping it.

So there is the process I did :

Dumping the actual database by using gzip to compress it a bit (super usefull for large databases) :

```
mysqldump -h ${HOST} -u ${USER} -p${PASSWORD} $1 | gzip > $2
```

Creating the temporary database :

```
mysql -e "CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS $1temp" -h ${HOST} -u ${USER} -p${PASSWORD}
```

Applicating the dump on the new database :

```
gunzip < $2 | mysql -h ${HOST} -u ${USER} -p${PASSWORD} $1"temp"
```

Updating the new database (in this example I use soundex to anonymize the data for a simplier example, but you can also affect real values by creating another database before with real names in it and randomly chose some in it to update this one :

```
mysql -e "UPDATE individu SET NAME=SOUNDEX(NAME)" $1"temp"
```

Dumping the temporary database into the  "real one" :

```
mysqldump -h ${HOST} -u ${USER} -p${PASSWORD} $1"temp" | gzip > $2
```

And finaly dropping the temporary database :

```
mysql -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS $1anom" -h ${HOST} -u ${USER} -p${PASSWORD} $1"temp"
```

Note: it might not be the optimal solution, but it fits very well my expectations, if you have a better solution, please write it below :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the dump from `mysqldump` is a regular text file. Regular Linux utilities exist to revise these file, such as `tr`, `sed`, and `awk`, and you can edit it manually using your favorite editor.

In your case, to anonymize the data, `sed` should be sufficient. Determine a pattern, then substitute `******` for full anonymity. If you want to replace with real looking data, e.g. John Smith, you can use `awk` to search and replace, or roll your own in the language of your choice.

I'm sure if you provide a sample record from the dump, with expected result, we can probably provide a full working example.

Comment: I just added an example in the initial message ;)
Btw, I am on Windows, is there some tools comparable to the ones you just gave to me ?

Comment: Look into bash utilities for Windows, `cygwin` is popular and has most of the Linux bash utilities, and I think it has a non-admin install if you don't have admin rights.